# Browser blocking popup Facebook permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have been creating Facebook apps for sometime now. I use the javascript SDK to trigger a popup to ask for the user's permissions. The popup is activated when the user clicks a button, so not on page load or by an event other than a click. Now recently browsers have been blocking the permissions popup where this NEVER used to be a problem in the past. Any ideas?

Thanks

Tyrone

Comment: You say "browsers" - have you identified any in particular, specifically those that you may have recently updated?

Comment: Definitely happening in chrome and some users reporting it happening in Firefox!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Facebook applications, there are several different options for display modes. `popup` is simply one of them.

You may be interested in using any of the following: `page`, `popup`, `touch` (mobile devices), and `iframe`. `page` may be the most convenient for you as `iframe` is disallowed for certain dialog functionality.

**Reference**: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

Enjoy and good luck!

Comment: Problem is that FB suggests "The OAuth Dialog should not be called directly from the JavaScript SDK. Rather, use FB.login for this purpose." Now if I use the non-suggested and not well documented FB.ui for permissions, the response returns a selected_profile, which is the users Id, but no auth token. Have you implemented this successfully? Only other way I see is redirect the user to the auth dialog by leaving the app itself then redirect them back.

Comment: Hi Tyrone, what is the server-side language you are using for Facebook? PHP?